# Jquery change input element (live)

Tags: jquery, replace, live

I got the following code to change text in a input if it has presence of a text set in the attribute texttoreplace of this same input:

```
    $(".replace_path").focusout(function() {
        $(".replace_path").val($(".replace_path").val().replace($(this).attr('texttoreplace'),""));
    });
```

Its working fine except I can only trigger when the focus is out. Is there a way to accomplish the same result triggering the event in case value > 0? Cause I got another java script source adding the text to that input. (its not being typed).

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

You can use change() event listener:

```
$('.replace_path').change(function() {
  if ( $('.replace_path').val() > 0 ){
    alert('Handler for .change() called.');
  }
});
```

But you should be careful about starting an infinite recursive loop, because focusout will update the value of .replace_path and this will trigger the change callback function.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with `.change()` and `.focusout()`, is that they both require the user to `.blur()` the event before it fires.

You can just trigger the event directly though:

```
function yourJavaScript() {
   $(".replace_path").val('your custom text');
   $(".replace_path").trigger('focusout');
}
```